# "karma start" memorizes the --grep pattern provided by the last "karma run"

Tags: karma-runner

I have a karma server running by `karma start karma.conf.js --no-single-run`, then I run single test by `karma run -- --grep=MyClass`. After this, when any of the included files is changed, it starts to run tests based on the last specified grep pattern, not all tests. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to create an issue in the karma-runner repository, but someone outstripped me ([issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2819)). This issue was marked as a bug, so the question can be closed.